# how to make every button perform the a function only on it's child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
        var button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
        for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
            button[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('element');
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    if (elements[i].style.background == "cornflowerblue") {
                        elements[i].style.background = "red"   
                    } else {
                        elements[i].style.background = "cornflowerblue"
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

```css
    <style>
        .groups-wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }
        .groups-wrapper .group {
            width: 30%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            border: thin solid #000;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }

        .groups-wrapper .group button {
            font-size: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .groups-wrapper .group .elements-wrapper {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            column-gap: 5px;
            row-gap: 5px;
        }

        .groups-wrapper .group .elements-wrapper .element {
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            background: cornflowerblue;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="groups-wrapper">

        <div class="group">
            <h3>Group 1</h3>
            <button class="btn">button</button>
            <div class="elements-wrapper">
                <div class="element">element</div>
                <div class="element">element</div>
                <div class="element">element</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <h3>Group 2</h3>
            <button class="btn">button</button>
            <div class="elements-wrapper">
                <div class="element">element</div>
                <div class="element">element</div>
                <div class="element">element</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <h3>Group 3</h3>
            <button class="btn">button</button>
            <div class="elements-wrapper">
                <div class="element">element</div>
                <div class="element">element</div>
                <div class="element">element</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

These are 3 groups every group contains a button and 6 elements, What the button does is changing the elements background to red, So in the JS I got all the buttons and all the elements, Now when I click the button it applies the function to all of the elements, What I want to do is when I click on any button it only apply the function on the elements in it's group and the other groups should remain the same.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Introduce the problem before you post any code** - In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible."_

Comment: Have a look at `this`, `.nextElementSibling` (and maybe `.children`)

Comment: OK, thank you I really appreciate your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) (using a single event handler for a bunch of elements to a single ancestor of those elements) makes your life easier. To identify the elements within the clicked buttons' ancestor (i.e. `div.group`) you can query `[clickedElement].closest(".group")` for the child `.element` elements within the `.elements-wrapper` block.

```js
const btnAction = evt => {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains("btn")) {
    //                                 ^ only if button.btn was clicked
    evt.target.closest(".group").querySelectorAll(".elements-wrapper .element")
      //       ^ parent.group                     | 
      //                                          ^ child .element nodes
      .forEach(elem => elem.style.background =
        elem.style.background === "cornflowerblue" || !elem.style.background ?
        "red" : "cornflowerblue");
  }
};

// add click handler to document
document.addEventListener("click", btnAction);
```

```css
<style>.groups-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.groups-wrapper .group {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: thin solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.groups-wrapper .group button {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.groups-wrapper .group .elements-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 5px;
  row-gap: 5px;
}

.groups-wrapper .group .elements-wrapper .element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="groups-wrapper">

  <div class="group">
    <h3>Group 1</h3>
    <button class="btn">button</button>
    <div class="elements-wrapper">
      <div class="element">element</div>
      <div class="element">element</div>
      <div class="element">element</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <h3>Group 2</h3>
    <button class="btn">button</button>
    <div class="elements-wrapper">
      <div class="element">element</div>
      <div class="element">element</div>
      <div class="element">element</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <h3>Group 3</h3>
    <button class="btn">button</button>
    <div class="elements-wrapper">
      <div class="element">element</div>
      <div class="element">element</div>
      <div class="element">element</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer:

I made some things here:

- Use a EventListener on `document` and not on every single button. This will reduce the number of active EventListeners
- Don't change inline styles. Change classNames instead.
- Don't change the class of every `.element` but of their parent wrapping element.
- Make small function that have a single purpose
- Wrap everything inside a block, so we can have coped variables inside this block

```js
{
  "use strict";
  const buttonSelector = ".btn";
  const containerSelector = ".group";
  const elementSelector = ".elements-wrapper";
  
  function toggleClassName(elements, className) {
    Array.from(elements).forEach(elem => elem.classList.toggle(className))
  }
  
  function onClick(e) {
    const button = e.target.closest(buttonSelector);
    if (!button) return;
    
    const container = e.target.closest(containerSelector);
    toggleClassName(container.querySelectorAll(elementSelector), 'highlight')
  }
  
  document.addEventListener('click', onClick)
}
```

```css
<style>
        .groups-wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
        }
        .groups-wrapper .group {
            width: 30%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            border: thin solid #000;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }

        .groups-wrapper .group button {
            font-size: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .groups-wrapper .group .elements-wrapper {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            column-gap: 5px;
            row-gap: 5px;
        }

        .groups-wrapper .group .elements-wrapper .element {
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            background: red;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .groups-wrapper .group .elements-wrapper.highlight .element {
            background: cornflowerblue;
        }
```

```html
<div class="groups-wrapper">

        <div class="group">
            <h3>Group 1</h3>
            <button class="btn">button</button>
            <div class="elements-wrapper">
                <div class="element">element</div>
                <div class="element">element</div>
                <div class="element">element</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <h3>Group 2</h3>
            <button class="btn">button</button>
            <div class="elements-wrapper">
                <div class="element">element</div>
                <div class="element">element</div>
                <div class="element">element</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <h3>Group 3</h3>
            <button class="btn">button</button>
            <div class="elements-wrapper">
                <div class="element">element</div>
                <div class="element">element</div>
                <div class="element">element</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you want to stay as near as possible to your original code, use this

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // here we don't use all elements, but only the elements inside the group element that our button is in.
    var elements = e.target.closest('.group').querySelectorAll('.element');
    // The following code change was done, because the first click didn't change a thing.
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if (elements[i].style.background == "red") {
        elements[i].style.background = ""
      } else {
        elements[i].style.background = "red"
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
<style>.groups-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.groups-wrapper .group {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: thin solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.groups-wrapper .group button {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.groups-wrapper .group .elements-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 5px;
  row-gap: 5px;
}

.groups-wrapper .group .elements-wrapper .element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="groups-wrapper">

  <div class="group">
    <h3>Group 1</h3>
    <button class="btn">button</button>
    <div class="elements-wrapper">
      <div class="element">element</div>
      <div class="element">element</div>
      <div class="element">element</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <h3>Group 2</h3>
    <button class="btn">button</button>
    <div class="elements-wrapper">
      <div class="element">element</div>
      <div class="element">element</div>
      <div class="element">element</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <h3>Group 3</h3>
    <button class="btn">button</button>
    <div class="elements-wrapper">
      <div class="element">element</div>
      <div class="element">element</div>
      <div class="element">element</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems a little bit for complicated me but I really appreciate your interest, thank you.

Comment: @SaifEssam Some of my suggestions are more of the general type.

Comment: @SaifEssam I added a second example which is closer to your original post. I advice you to walk through my first example to understand, what it does and to contemplate, why I might have done this